# VBA Userform Find function display records

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in the process of making a userform. I have managed to setup a find function using the code below which then also loops and counts the number of cases in the spreadsheet.

I have also created a function to find the next item which is operated by a separate command button but it does not display the records in the userform so it can be amended.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

```
Private Sub FindNext_Click()
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub Find_Click()
    Worksheets("Master").Activate
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Set rSearch = Range("a1", Range("e65536").End(xlUp))
    Dim f      As Integer

    strFind = Me.TextBox1.Value

    With rSearch
        Set c = .Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.Select
            With Me
                .TextBox2.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                .TextBox3.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
                .TextBox4.Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
                .TextBox5.Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
                .TextBox6.Value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
                .TextBox7.Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value
                .TextBox8.Value = c.Offset(0, 7).Value
                .TextBox9.Value = c.Offset(0, 8).Value
                .TextBox10.Value = c.Offset(0, 9).Value
                .TextBox11.Value = c.Offset(0, 10).Value
                .TextBox12.Value = c.Offset(0, 11).Value
                .TextBox13.Value = c.Offset(0, 12).Value
                .TextBox14.Value = c.Offset(0, 13).Value
                .TextBox20.Value = c.Offset(0, 14).Value
                .TextBox21.Value = c.Offset(0, 15).Value
                .TextBox15.Value = c.Offset(0, 16).Value
                .TextBox22.Value = c.Offset(0, 17).Value
                .TextBox16.Value = c.Offset(0, 18).Value
                .TextBox18.Value = c.Offset(0, 19).Value
                .TextBox19.Value = c.Offset(0, 20).Value
                .update.Enabled = True
                .Add.Enabled = False
                f = 0
            End With
            FirstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                f = f + 1
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
            If f > 1 Then
                Select Case MsgBox("There are " & f & " instances of " & strFind, vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Multiple entries")

                    Case vbOK
                    Case vbCancel

                End Select
                Me.Height = frmMax

            End If
        Else: MsgBox strFind & " not listed"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: "it does not display the records in the userform so it can be amended." I do not understand. You haven't written any code that would put the values on the form, as you have done for the Find procedure? All you do is activate a cell - why would you expect it to do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *encapsulate the update code* into its own method (sub) then you can call it for both Find and Find Next. Like:

```
Private Sub FindNext_Click()
    Dim nextCell As Range
    Set nextCell = Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell)
    'FindNext loops round to the initial cell if it finds no other so we test for it
    If Not nextCell.Address(external:=true) = ActiveCell.Address(external:=true) Then
        updateFields anchorCell:=nextCell
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Find_Click()
    Worksheets("Master").Activate
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Set rSearch = Range("a1", Range("e65536").End(xlUp))
    Dim f      As Integer

    strFind = Me.TextBox1.Value

    With rSearch
        Set c = .Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            updateFields anchorCell:=c
            FirstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                f = f + 1
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
            If f > 1 Then
                Select Case MsgBox("There are " & f & " instances of " & strFind, vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Multiple entries")

                    Case vbOK
                    Case vbCancel

                End Select
                Me.Height = frmMax

            End If
        Else: MsgBox strFind & " not listed"
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub updateFields(anchorCell As Range)
    anchorCell.Select
    With Me
        .TextBox2.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        .TextBox3.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        .TextBox4.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        .TextBox5.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        .TextBox6.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
        .TextBox7.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        .TextBox8.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        .TextBox9.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
        .TextBox10.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
        .TextBox11.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
        .TextBox12.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
        .TextBox13.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
        .TextBox14.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
        .TextBox20.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 14).Value
        .TextBox21.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 15).Value
        .TextBox15.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 16).Value
        .TextBox22.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
        .TextBox16.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
        .TextBox18.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
        .TextBox19.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
        .Update.Enabled = True
        .Add.Enabled = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Cor Blimey your a star, I've never heard of anchor cell it's great. Oh and it works thanks for the help I couldn't get how to activate the find next function in my brain.

Comment: @MattW anchorCell is just a variable name I call the range cell. It isn't a class itself - just a range variable. Glad it helps. As a tip, it is good to try and split code into seperate procedures containing logical blocks (like the updateFields procedure I split out above). It helps with reusability and keeps code cleaner allowing you to focus on the overall flow and 'intent' of a given procedure.